# Sorting of Sys Categories

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

How can I sort alphabetically in the backend of TYPO3 system categories . Here UID seems to be preset .
Currently, main and sub-categories are listed in order of their creation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a PHP file inside your sitepackage *EXT:my_sitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_category.php*

with following content

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_category']['ctrl']['sortby'] = null;
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_category']['ctrl']['default_sortby'] = 'ORDER BY title';
```

to override default settings

Comment: Instead the EXT: site package I could also be a new EXT. anlgen and then adjust the TCA there, right?

EXT: site package is not available for TYPO3 7.6 LTS.

Comment: Yes, extension sitepackage means you should create and maintain your own named extension with all kind adaptions to your TYPO3 installation.